# export translate() and connect(mapStateToProps) from the same react-native file

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I use i18N component within my react-native application and I'm also about to implement redux to my app. I need to export both `connect(mapStateToProps)` and `translate()` from my entryPage.js file. I tried to export them seperately, like

```
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(entryPage);
module.exports = translate()(entryPage);
```

But, in this case below one do not exported I guess.

On the other hand, if I try to export them together like

```
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)translate()(entryPage);
```

I face an error.

I tried to solve with `compose-function`. But I got an empty screen and warning message.

Here is my `entryPage.js` file.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import compose from 'compose-function';
import {changeLang} from '../actions';

 class entryPage extends Component {


    changeLang(lang){
        console.log(lang);
        this.props.dispatch(changeLang(lang));
    }

    render() {

        console.log("This Props.t: ",this.props.t);
        const { t, i18n } = this.props;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={{marginBottom: 100, width: 55, height: 50,borderWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'black'}} value={this.props.currentLang} editale={false}/>
                <Text>Languages</Text>
                    <Button onPress={() => { i18n.changeLanguage('en'),this.changeLang("English") }} title="English"/>
                    <Button onPress={() => { i18n.changeLanguage('fr'),this.changeLang("French") }} title="French"/>
                    <Button onPress={() => { i18n.changeLanguage('de'),this.changeLang("German") }} title="German"/>
                    <Button onPress={()=>Actions.second()} title={t('entryPage:goToPage2')}/>
                <Text>{t('entryPage:simpleText')}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {
    return {
        currentLang: state.curretLang
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    separate: {
        marginTop: 50
    }
});

export default compose(translate, connect(mapStateToProps))(entryPage);
```

Here is [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbZBL.jpg) I faced.

Can you help me please? How can I solve this issue. I need both of them to be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a `compose`-function comes in handy, instead of doing something like:

```
export default translate(connect(mapStateToProps))(entryPage)
```

You can simply do:

```
export default compose(translate, connect(mapStateToProps))(entryPage)
```

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compose-function) is a `compose`-function published on NPM, there are also `compose`-functions bundled in many popular libraries like Ramda, Recompose  or Redux.

Comment: I think that the problem is one of exporting, not of composing 2 HoCs. btw - redux exports a compose method.

Comment: @OriDrori To me it looks like he's trying to compose multiple HOCs together, as he want to export a component that is using both redux connect and translate? And yeah compose functions are everywhere 

Comment: You might be right - `module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)translate()(entryPage);`.

Comment: Thanks man. I tried your solution. I got an empty white screen and warning message. I'm going to share my code and the warning screen.

Comment: @AliZeynalov Ah, that is because it seems that `translate` is a HOC-creator function, so you need to do `compose(translate(), everythingElse)` try that?